# Register Type which is based on Request cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm using Autofac and my types registration looks like:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
    static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;
    public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider  { get { return   _containerProvider; }}

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var myCookie = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];

        if (myCookie != null)
            builder.RegisterType<FirstService>().As<IService>().InstancePerRequest();
        else
            builder.RegisterType<SecondService>().As<IService>().InstancePerRequest();

       _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
    }
}
```

But it gives an error saying "Request is not available in this context". Can I register my types in another way to be able to use information from `Request` before?

Comment: Of course you can't use information from the request that yet to come to the server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application_Start` is called once while the application start and the *autofac* container is build for the global application, you would not want to register a service based on one `Request` here.

In order to do what you want, you can register both service as named service and add a third registration which resolve the correct named registration based on the cookie value. ie :

```
builder.RegisterType<FirstService>().Named<IService>("first").InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<SecondService>().Named<IService>("second").InstancePerRequest();


builder.Register(c => {
    var myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];

    if (myCookie != null)
        return c.ResolveNamed<IService>("first"); 
    else
        return c.ResolveNamed<IService>("second"); 
}).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Just realized that i need resolving per request and of course my approach is totally wrong. Cyril, big thanks! That works fine.